# can't partition hard drive correctly during installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I want to install ubuntu to my pc which has windows 7 already installed. My windows has 3 partitions C:, D: and E:. During Ubuntu installation i want to delete my C: and D: drives and install ubuntu on C:. I created 2 new partition after deleting C and D , one for primary mount at / and other for swap area.

But the problem is that after creating partitions for Ubuntu from unallocated space of C , the unallocated space of D drive remain unused. 
I can't make any other partition because i already have 4 partitions and i don't want to delete my E: drive.
How can i adjust unallocated space of D: drive to other drives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowed to make a maximum of 4 primary partitions in a Disk thats why it cant create a 5th one. The solution to this you can use a partition tool like gparted which comes in ubuntu live cd or even bootable flash drive and create an EXTENDED PARTITION by choosing Create As : Extended Partition instead of Primary Partition